# How to use Local / User Control with different folder

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have one question.

I don't want to duplicate my code so i see that i can use : User Control / Local
The problem is when i use local, i can just only call the file who is in the same folder as this one, and i wanna call my file in another folder.

Example :

in my Layout/_Menu.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TeysserWP8.Views.misc._menuLayout"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TeysserWP8.Views.misc"
    xmlns:drawerLayout="using:DrawerLayout"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF563AA0" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Button Command="{Binding MyDietViewCommand}" Content="Mes Régimes" Margin="10,21,0,502" Width="245"></Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding DietStoreViewCommand}" Content="Régimes Store" Margin="10,89,0,434" Width="245"></Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding LogoutViewCommand}" Content="Déconnexion" Margin="10,502,0,21" Width="245"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

in my Store/Show.xaml

```
<Grid>
  some code
</Grid>
<local:/Layout/_Menu />  <-- i Want something like this but its not work.
```

If the _Menu.xaml file was in the same folder than Show.xaml ( Store Folder ), its will work.

Can you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Just add a namespace mapping for the namespace that the control you want to use is located in, similar to the `xmlns:local="using:TeysserWP8.Views.misc"` line. See [Mapping to custom classes and assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747086%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: yeah , you right , thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think that this has something to do with folders. In XAML the local alias is used most of the time when referring to the namespace in which the current class exists. It is not something mandatory.

Check that the class you want to refer to

```
<local:/Layout/_Menu />
```

is in the namespase that you declared at the top of your XAML file. For your case, check in `TeysserWP8.Views.misc` namespace

```
xmlns:local="using:TeysserWP8.Views.misc"
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me after adding the wanted namespace:  `xmlns:local="using:TeysserWP8.Views.misc"`.